# Firebase/Firestore query. Unhandled exception: The query requires an index

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuEuP.jpg) I have a problem with Firestore as I get the error ***the query requires an index***. When I try to create it by clicking the provided url, it says you don't have permission. Any help please [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqZQJ.jpg)

Comment: Be sure to open the link in a browser window where you are signed into a Google account that is an editor on the Firebase project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the project is not selected and usually it happens when you have multiple gmail accounts,

If this is your case without changing url, select the correct gmail account from top right of screen, then select your project and create index

Comment: @AhmedMahdy, glad to help, please mark my post as correct answer, also you would get 2 points